# Argument 2: Cannot convert from bool to System.Func<DAL.Cash, bool>

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I was working on implementing a logic where I faced a problem that said `Argument 2: Cannot convert from bool to System.Func<DAL.Cash, bool>`

So basically, the line which's generating the error code is

```
result.thisWeekCash = cashToDate.Where(tradeDate.CompareTo(thisWeekBeginDate)>=0 || tradeDate.CompareTo(thisWeekEndDate)<=0).Sum(x=>x.profit);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot the lambda expression: `Where(x=>tradeDate.CompareTo(tx.hisWeekBeginDate)`

Comment: Ok, I post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the lambda expression:

```cs
Where( x=> // <-- this
   tradeDate.CompareTo(tx.hisWeekBeginDate) // ...
```

You can learn about [lambda expression on Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).